# Realtek High Definition Audio Codecs

Tags: sound, realtek

I've a Lenovo Y550 laptop with dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows &. I've installed **Realtek High Definition Audio Codecs** in windows installation. When I hear audio in Ubuntu it has less effect than Windows. In Ubuntu I am using the default installation settings. Is there anything I can do to make it better?

Answer (score 3):

go to http://www.realtek.com/downloads/ and download the driver for UNIX/Linux

Then go to the downloaded location and extract the file.

Inside that folder, there's a file named INSTALL, double click it and when prompted click run in terminal.

Finally Reboot.

Comment: Can I ask, is there any reason to install these codecs on Ubuntu?

Comment: INSTALL is just a text file for me with instructions. I followed those instructions and now I have no sound at all. :-(

Comment: Unable to compile drivers from http://www.realtek.com/downloads/ Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This link exists no more...

Answer (score 0):

go to http://152.104.125.41/downloads/ and select High Definition Audio Codecs (Software) you find the driver for Linux which is about to 4.5 MB in size. you can find complete installation guide on in the compressed folder.

Comment: The link has stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Sound settings** and check **Allow louder than 100%** .
You will get the issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This particular thread need a lot of updating.

In the instructions for the codec we are making the codec to install it, there is no simple "install" there.

And when we make the codec we have to use some command "./configure" which my 21.04 Ubuntu doesn't even recognize at all.

Hope someone with a lot more knowledge of Linux than myself updates this thread because I could really use this driver since my system is making weird noises when I turn up the audio to certain levels. To me PulseAudio is the problem and is trash. I try alternatives but none seem to install well and it may simply be the lack of a driver for HD audio but when the instructions in the package from Realtek include commands that don't exist there is no answer to this question in this thread.

Comment: Seems you may not fully understand how this site works. This is a question and answer site not a forum so there are no threads. The original question is over 9 years old so of course some things may be different in a new version.